# Weird Hex to Decimal Conversion

Tags: c, math, hex, decimal

Somebody is passing me data in an odd (wrong) format. To parse it I need:

0x34 = 34

NOT 0x34 = 52 (as it does in real life)

So, essentially just ripping off the hex and pretending it was supposed to be decimal the whole time.

Any help?

Edit: To make it easier I need something like this:

int i = 52 is passed into a function that returns an int of 34

int i = 85 yields an int of 55

Double edit: had some stuff backwards. I am struggling tonight haha.

Comment: String argument to function, or read from file?  What have you tried?  It can be done with an appropriate `scanf()` format, such as `”0x%d”` would do the job.

Comment: ...just remove the first two characters?

Comment: It's held in a char * convertable to int. Bluetooth Low Energy communication. Sorry for the lack of clarification.

Comment: I just need a math formula really. I can figure out the rest.

Comment: the char * doesn't actually contain "0x" to remove haha. That's just me designating that it's encoded hex because of whoever is sending it to me. But not how it's being read in. It's basically just a math problem.

Comment: So basically you're getting data in BCD format and trying to convert that to a normal binary integer.

Comment: What do you mean "encoded hex" is it a string or not?

Comment: That sounds correct actually.

Comment: The element is index [3] of a char * for ... reasons

Comment: I'm making it too complicated. Pretend it's an just an int. I have int i = 52; I need int i = 34; Based on the oddball scenario presented above.

Comment: Edited to explain better.

Comment: that's not weird but is actually [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) that is commonly used in the past and still widely in use in many applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with unsigned int:

```
unsigned int convert(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int m;

    r = 0;
    m = 1;
    while (n) {
        r += m * (n & 0xf);
        n >>= 4;
        m *= 10;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Here's the inverse function:

```
unsigned int iconvert(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int s;

    r = 0;
    s = 0;
    while (n) {
        r += (n % 10) << s;
        n /= 10;
        s += 4;
    }

    return r;
}
```

So `convert(34) = 52` and `iconvert(52) = 34`.

Comment: This might be it. Can you verify with the edits I've made? I did a poor job of explaining.

Comment: @user2985888 `convert(0x34)`, i.e. `convert(52)` produces `34`.  Is this what you want?  Or do you want the inverse of this?  The original post implied this, but the edits imply the inverse.  I can add the inverse as well, give me a minute.

Comment: I've edited again. This appears right. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Ok I added both the forward and inverse versions - take your pick!

Comment: I'm just having a crap night lol. I'll accept this. I verified as it works. My edits were just poor.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need ?

```
char * strip_hex_prefix( char *str)
{
    if( str && ( strlen(str) > 2 )  && (strncmp(tolower(str),"0x",2) == 0) )
       return str+2;
}
```

or simply in code directly

```
if( str && ( strlen(str) > 2 )  && (strncmp(tolower(str),"0x",2) == 0) )
   str += 2;
```

and to move further in converting to a decimal

```
int hex_2_dec(char *str)
{   
    int len = strlen(str);
    int base = 1;
    int dec_val = 0;

    for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--)
    {   
        if (str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9')
        {
            dec_val += (str[i] - 48)*base;
            base = base * 16;
        }
        else if (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='F')
        {
            dec_val += (str[i] - 55)*base;
            base = base*16;
        }
    }
    return dec_val;
}
```